# Merging multiple managed and unmanaged dlls into single single dll with Fody Costura

Tags: c#, .net, dll, fody-costura

I'm embedding multiple 3rd party managed and unmanaged dlls into one dll.

That single dll gets picked up and injected into another host application at runtime ussing `Assembly.Load`
The entire thing is supposed to work as a host with plugins thing. (just to clarify)

I have it working for all dlls (managed, unmanaged and mixed) except for one: VideoOS.Platform.SDK.Export, for which I get 
dll not found exception on runtime, the dll is from Milestone NVR SDK

I've tried:

- putting it as IncludeAssemblies, Unmanaged32Assemblies and Unmanaged64Assemblies
- toggling: compression, temp files on disk
- manually loading it from the resources with: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`
- decompiling the library itself with (Reflector, DotPeek, ILSpy) they all turn up with issues, so I'm thinking    it's probabbly some pinvokes or similar that they can't decompile.

Notes:

1. The whole process works when the dll is in the same folder as the host app exe but not when it's embededd
2. I had an issue with a referenced library that started working when put in Unmanaged32Assemblies was resolved OK

Comment: Pleasy specify some code for manual AssemblyResolve event

Comment: Used this code: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_press/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition/  , triple checked resource name, it gets loaded without any problems, but the exception persists

Comment: Is it called for this dll? Did you check that ResolveEventArgs.Name contains your "VideoOS.Platform.SDK.Export" name when event is called?

Comment: Yes, and its found in the resources, read (checked stream length on debug), and loaded